# How to detect the clicked href URL in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to detect the clicked href URL in JQuery? For example I have the following links, some is redirect to the new page and some will call to the javascript to expand the div. How can I use the JQuery/Javascript to detect the href if no ID been use.

```
<a href="www.test.com">Test 1</a>
<a href="javascript:test()">Test 2</a>
<a href="www.test2.com">Test 3</a>
<a href="www.test3.com">Test 4</a>
<a href="javascript:test2()">Test 5</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _detect the href_?

Comment: I am confused about the 'selected' word.  Are you talking about when someone is using the tab key to move through the tabable objects?  Or, are you asking to detect which one has been clicked?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to detect the clicked href URL in JQuery?

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    // Capture the href from the selected link...
    var link = this.href;

    alert(link);

    // do something if required....

    // would prevent the link from executing, if that is something you want to do...
    return false; // not needed if you want the link to execute normally...
});
```